Iterate through a variable in your SQL table to set ID numbers incrementing by 1 for each record?
WHILE [production].[stocks].[id] = 1
BEGIN
   update [production].[stocks].[id]
set id = id + 1
END



I was attempting to loop through the id variable starting with 1 at the first record and then iterating through each record adding +1 every record the entire length of the table. Store and product id are currently a compound primary key, but I am trying to make this id field so then I can make them both foreign keys. I am assuming I am indexing incorrectly, also was planning on putting a conditional statement with a length function on id so that it stops looping when the the id variable meets the integer returned from the length function. However, I don't know where to place this. Thanks for the help.

sample data and desired output are highly welcome and help us to help you

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

"I was attempting to loop through the id" ➰ Ng is normally the last thing you should be doing. SQL is a set based language, don't excels at set based solutions. Using a loop is very likely the last thing you actually should be using. Why do you want to loop specifically?

Loops should be avoided when possible.   Consider an UPDATE cte and the window functions like row_number() and/or dense_rank()

No, they shouldn't be linked and they shouldn't be images. See the link Thom posted.

select store_id,product_id,quantity, row_number()over(order by store_id)as ID. Please try this

Show us some sample, raw data, and the desired results that will be produced for that data.

I really should have paid attention that autocorrect changed loop to ➰>_<

with data as (select *, row_number() over (order by product_id) rn from production.stocks) update data set id = rn where id = 1

    -- Steps to create the scenario on your local version of SQL Server    
    if  exists (select * from [sys].[objects] WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[production].[stocks]') AND [type] in (N'U'))
    drop table [production].[stocks];
    GO
    
    if exists (select 1 from [sys].[schemas] where [name] = 'production')
    drop schema production;
    GO
    
    create schema production;
    GO
    
    create table [production].[stocks] 
    (
    [store_id] int, 
    [product_id] int, 
    [quantity] int,
    [id] int
    );
    GO
    
    insert into [production].[stocks] 
    values
    (1,1,27,1),
    (1,2,5,1),
    (1,3,6,1),
    (1,4,23,1),
    (1,5,22,1),
    (1,6,0,1),
    (1,7,8,1),
    (1,8,0,1),
    (1,9,11,1),
    (1,10,15,1),
    (1,11,8,1),
    (1,12,16,1),
    (1,13,13,1),
    (1,14,8,1),
    (1,15,3,1),
    (1,16,4,1),
    (1,17,2,1),
    (1,18,16,1),
    (1,19,4,1);
    
    -- Create a Common Table Expression to re-create the original table with the addition of a new field called 'Rank' (this is just the name I usually use) that uses a window function to auto-number based on [product_id] and [store_id]. 
    -- We are essentially creating a unique sort ID. 
    -- If there are multiple rows with the same [product_id] and [store_id], this will still generate unique IDs. 
    -- If your table has a datetime field that represents the created date, that would be the ideal candidate to use in the 'order by' clause of the window function instead of using [product_id] and [store_id].
    with cte as 
    (
    select 
    [rank] = row_number() over (order by [product_id], [store_id]), 
    [store_id],
    [product_id], 
    [quantity]
    from 
    [production].[stocks]
    )
    
    -- Join your original table to the CTE using all of the key join fields so that you can use the new 'Rank' field to update the [Id] field in your existing table
    update s 
    set [Id] = cte.[rank]
    from 
    [production].[stocks] s 
    inner join cte on cte.[store_id] = s.[store_id] and cte.[product_id] = s.[product_id] and cte.[quantity] = s.[quantity];
    
    select * from [production].[stocks];


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
